# Change worspress read more button text

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a problem with Read More button.

Here is a link to my website: http://kamilawosinska-skillspring.com/index.php/publikacje/

As you can see all site is in Polish but Read More button is in English

I can't change it. I tried Loco translator but it does not work.

Do you have any idea how to change Read More button text?

I use Bstone theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'change_read_more_to_something' );
function change_read_more_to_something() {
    add_filter( 'gettext', 'change_read_more_text');
}

function change_read_more_text( $text ) {
 
    $text = str_ireplace( 'Read More',  'YOUR TEXT',  $text );
    return $text;
}
```

Add this code to your `functions.php`

This should work but remember this will change all `Read More`

Comment: Hi it looks like you already have option in your theme.
The code get the Read more text from settings http://prntscr.com/2002z0u

Comment: Do you know where this option can be located? I searched it for a long time with no results.

Comment: Looks like this settings are in PRO version of my theme.